# Nginx whitelist API requests from same server as client, block all others

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application with a couple of API endpoints using Django Rest Framework that I want to only be accessible by the Django application itself. I'm trying to restrict access those endpoints via nginx but everything I've tried either results in a 403 fobidden response on all clients or is able to be accessed by all clients.

Below is my nginx config. I've also tried replacing `127.0.0.1` with the IP of the server but that results in the same responses mentioned above.

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream api_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /endpoint1/ {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /endpoint2/ {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /path/to/static/;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

TL;DR I have a Django API that should only accept requests from the Django app running alongside it. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you explain why you want your application to call itself via HTTP, rather than simply calling the functions within the Python code?

Comment: The Django app serves a web page which is what's calling the API.

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Why can't the Django app import the functions and call them?

Comment: The web page takes input from the user, passes that input to the API via AJAX, and displays the response to the user.

Comment: So are you saying that the request you need is Ajax from the browser to the API? In which case you don't want to restrict the access to the server at all, surely; the requests aren't coming from the server, they're coming from the browser.

Comment: The issue is ensuring that the only requests received and/or accepted by the API originate from the web client served by the Django app. How would you accomplish that?

Comment: Some kind of authentication - shared secret, bearer token, JWT, etc.

Comment: This is a publicly available site though so there’s no inherent user auth. Any token that the web client uses to authenticate to the API would also be exposed to the user thus allowing them to access the API on their own.

Comment: So why do you need to restrict it to coming from a certain page?